# I don't get this ruby syntax

Tags: ruby

What does =~ mean in ruby? Here is my code:

```
    File.open("Safeway.html") do |f|
      f.each do |line|
        puts line if line =~ /"\/recipe\//
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby took some things from perl. In perl, regex matching is done with the =~ operator. Some people believe you should write code that can never be mistaken for perl, and in that case you can use Regexp#match() or String#match().  If you use String#match(), e.g.:

```
'hello'.match('.')
```

Ruby just converts the argument, i.e. '.', into a Regexp and then calls Regexp#match() on the Regexp.

I prefer to write:

```
md = my_str.match /my_regex/
```

and then test the MatchData object to see if there was a match:

```
md = my_str.match /my_regex/  

if md  #do something
  puts md[0]  #the whole match
  ...
```

If there is no match, md is set equal to nil.  Check the MatchData class for all the info a MatchData object provides:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html

Answer (score 1):

[`=~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) is the operator for regexp match. It takes it's operands (one a string, another a regexp), and returns nil for no match or the index of the index of the match for a match.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it means "matches". In this case it's a method on `String`, so you can clearly see what it means by looking at the [docs for `String#=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E):

> Match—If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str,and returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match. Otherwise, invokes obj.=~, passing str as an argument. The default =~ in Object returns nil.
>
> Note: str =~ regexp is not the same as regexp =~ str. Strings captured from named capture groups are assigned to local variables only in the second case.
>
> ```
> "cat o' 9 tails" =~ /\d/   #=> 7
> "cat o' 9 tails" =~ 9      #=> nil
> ```

Comment: What is the advanced part of its meaning?

Comment: @sawa The remaining part of my answer addresses that, for the most part. (Think basic vs detailed, not basic vs advanced.)